# Why isn't box-shadow working?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I can't seem to get box-shadow to work for my div element with the following CSS code:

```
#header {
background-color: #B89E70;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 5%;
position: fixed;
box-shadow: 0px, 20px, 5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);


font-family: arial;
text-align: center;
}
```

I'm using Chrome. Any ideas of what I might've missed?

Comment: Looking at the inspector reveals "Invalid property value". Remove the commas between the values. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: Thank you! Getting way too tired for this! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value for the `box-shadow` shouldn't have commas in it. The `box-shadow` property uses commas to separate multiple shadows.

You should update your `box-shadow` like this:

```
box-shadow: 0px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
```

Keep in mind that you can display multiple shadows on one box like this:

```
box-shadow: 0px 20px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), 5px -5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

You can make some pretty cool effects that way!